# Alternating positive and negative numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a SQL Server database and there is a table "COST OF PRODUCTS" (> 600,000 rows). I have to make a query that shows which products have changed the price. As you can see below: 1,2,3 rows, because 1st is positive and 2nd is negative; 3rd is positive. As I understand, I must create an additional table and check using inner join or use Lag/Lead function.

Who knows what's the better way to do it?

```
ID | COST | CHANGE
 1 | 450  |  1,4
 2 | 350  | -0,8
 3 | 470  |  1,2
 4 | 550  |  1,3
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the data *into the question* in a table format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I understand English is not your native language, but your question is not yet clear.  In the 'change' column, you have numbers with a comma; does that comma indicate the decimal point in your locale?  Is that number an absolute change or a percentage change?  Is the cost column an integer or a floating point value?  You need to show 'which products have changed the price'. I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Is that all products with a non-zero value in the Change column? _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  You ask for alternating positive and negative numbers; but it is not clear which numbers are alternating, and what you should do if there are 350,000 rows with a positive change and 250,000 rows with a negative change.  Also, alternating depends on a sequencing — that is, the results of a query are a set of rows, and sets are not ordered.  To impose the 'alternating' requirement, you have to order the results (ORDER BY in SQL).  But what are you sorting?  So, you need to clarify what you are seeking to do in a number of ways before we're able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.  It seems they've all changed the price, so `where change <> 0`. How does alternating positive and negative come into it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, I want just to see rows in sequence: + - + - + - + in column Change :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the data listed with positive first, and then negative you can either do:

```
SELECT * FROM COST_OF_PRODUCTS
WHERE CHANGE>0
UNION
SELECT * FROM COST_OF_PRODUCTS
WHERE CHANGE<0
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM COST_OF PRODUCTS
ORDER BY CHANGE
```

Comment: note that the first one (using the `UNION`) will exclude when change = 0, but that can be included by changing one of the `>` or `<` to `>=` or `<=`.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what i want, your query shows ++++++   ---------, but I need to see which rows have alternating values + - + - + - + -